# c3p0 методы получения DataSource

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, c3p0

Добрый вечер! Подскажите, пож

c3p0  методы получения DataSource  -

```
DataSources.unpooledDataSource(String jdbcUrl, Properties driverProps)
```

и

```
DataSources.pooledDataSource( DataSource unpooledDataSource, Map overrideProps )
```

работают с одними и теми же пропертями?

при создании пула коннекшнов можно создавать unpooledDataSource просто по урлу драйвера + логин пароль к БД и уже в pooledDataSource указывать переопределением провертей пула колво коннекшнов, стейтментов, время жизни итд итп - правильно? или набор пропертей которые указываются в сигнутуры методов сетятся в разные мапы параметров датасорса который я буду вытягивать из созданного пула?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Properties driverProps` могут содержать только Properties JDBC драйвера, которые, обычно, содержат только `user` и `password`

`Map overrideProps` же может содержать все остальные свойства. См. [c3p0's configuration properties](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_properties).

Хотя обычно `overrideProps` не используют и свойства все прописывают в файлах конфигурации (обычно в `c3p0.properties`, хотя c3p0  предлагает множество способов задания конфигурации).

Скорее всего вам будет удобнее [создать ComboPooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_combopooleddatasource). В общем все свойства в ваших `config` становятся дефолтными, но их всегда можно переопределить методами `setXXX` (где `XXX` это любая настройка/свойство).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to hear . I can not use ComboPooledDataSource because I need to use the jdbc db properties, such as the PACKETSIZE in sybase ase and some other properties in different db (postgres, oracle)

Comment: I'm glad to help. Even if you do with to use nonstandard JDBC driver properties, you can use ComboPooledDataSource if you wish. ComboPooledDataSource has a method called `setProperties(...)`, which defined the JDBC driver properties that will be used. If you use this method, just be sure to define the standard JDBC driver properties `user` and `password` yourself.

Comment: (If you really want to, you can call `setProperties(...)` first with just the nonstandard properties, and then `setUser(...)` and `setPassword(...)`, but it's simpler if you are defining the JDBC driver properties object yourself just to set the keys `user` and `password` directly.)